# L-sentence which expresses bijective function

Tags: logic, model-theory

I've stumbled upon this exercise from "Sets, Models, Proofs" and can't seem to find a solution. It goes like this:

> Let $L$ be a language with just one 1-place function symbol $F$. Give
>   an $L$-sentence $\phi$ which expresses that $F$ is a bijective
>   function.

Sadly, I'm completely stuck. Any help would be dearly appreciated!

Comment: You have to "formalize" the definition of [bijection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) : "For a pairing between X and Y to be a bijection, four properties must hold: each element of X must be paired with at least one element of Y; no element of X may be paired with more than one element of Y; each element of Y must be paired with at least one element of X; and no element of Y may be paired with more than one element of X."

Comment: @Mauro I guess this depends on how you look at it but since we are told that $F$ is a function, I think the first two conditions will automatically be built in to any theory in the language.

Comment: You will need the language to include at least the equality sign in addition to $F$ - you must have at least one relation in the language, or there are no formulas at all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us assume that equality is built into the formalism you are using, so that we can use it -- otherwise, the exercise makes no sense.

Now, $F$ is bijective if and only if it is both injective and surjective:

> - $F$ is injective iff $F(x) = F(y)$ implies $x = y$ for all $x$ and $y$; equivalently, iff $x \ne y$ implies $F(x) \ne F(y)$.
> - $F$ is surjective iff $x = F(y)$ for every $x$.

For injectivity, we can therefore use the following formula:

$$\phi_i:\qquad  \forall x: \forall y: F(x) = F(y) \to x = y$$

For surjectivity, we want to express that *for every $x$*, there *exists* an $y$ such that $x = F(y)$:

$$\phi_s:\qquad \forall x: \exists y: x = F(y)$$

Therefore, by definition of bijectivity, we may define the formula $\phi$ characterising that $F$ is a bijection as:

$$\phi: \qquad \phi_i \land \phi_s$$